# running a bigquery command across multiple projetcs

Tags: command-line, google-bigquery

Is it possible to run a bq command which query a dataset on project X and stores the result on another dataset on project Y:

```
bq query  --destination_table=project_Y.dataset_1.table_1 "SELECT * FROM project_X.dataset2.table_2"
```

What about the credentials now that I have two projects involved?
 I only have set a service account credential for project_X using gcloud.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Queries across multiple projects are supported.

The user (or service account) issuing the query will need to have the appropriate permissions on each project (and/or dataset).

You can read more about BigQuery permissions here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control

Comment: When I create a service account, it creates the service account for the current project. How can I create a service account for more than one projects?

Comment: You should be able to add the service account from one of your projects to the other projects/datasets (in the IAM permissions in console.cloud.google.com)